# Updating to a particular version of node: paths being strange?

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, path

I'm trying to update node (on Ubuntu) and have been using the n package to do this.

I've run the following:

```
$ sudo npm install -g n
% sudo n 0.10.21
```

This appeared to run OK, but now I get the following:

```
$ which node
/usr/local/bin/node

$ node -v
0.6.4

$ /usr/local/bin/node -v
0.10.4
```

which is baffling to me.

How can I get rid of 0.6.4 and ensure that 0.10.4 is what runs when I type `node`?

Comment: Does `node -v` work in a new shell?

Comment: I used `nvm` to fix this in the end.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a shell issue.  I've only seen it in bash, but here goes:

Bash caches where it has found commands in the past.  This means that if you place an executable (with the same name as something you've run before) earlier in the PATH, `which` will correctly find the new one, but bash will hit the cache and run the old one.

The easiest fix is simply to close your shell and open a new one.  However, you can aldo use the command `hash -d node` to clear `node` from the cache (or `type node` to see whether it is in the cache and what it is pointing to).